# Google Analytics V3 and C# Sample

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I have been tasked with connecting to Google Analytics and pulling the data from an account. I have been trying to figure that out. Does anyone know of a working sample I could use? I have found some code on stackoverflow but I continue to get 'User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile' though I believe my account is correctly setup.

Comment: just curious,did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Google provides Data API. You can use that.

Refer: [Core Reporting API - Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide)

The Core Reporting API provides access to the tabular data in Google Analytics standard and custom reports. To access data, you create a query that specifies: the profile, the start and end dates, and the dimensions and metrics that make up the column headers in the table. This query is sent to the Core Reporting API and The Core Reporting API returns all the data in the form of a table

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer my questions. I started at that site.

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that the user does not have sufficient permissions for the entity specified in the query.

The solution are 2:

Your account is misconfigurated (doublecheck it)

You are passing the wrong credential (check your OAuth 2.0 clientID and apikey)

Comment: That is what I am guessing but I can't see what is wrong. The email I am using is listed at a team member "Is ownder" rights and is active. Is the account google created for me when I went through the Auth2.0 process. Under API Access, I am using the p12 key they generated for me and using the correct profile ID, I took it from the URL when I go to my dashboard.

Comment: @user147372 not profileId but clientId. you get it in the google api console above the apikey. it is something like 1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com

Comment: Client ID:  
xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address:  
xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com

I used both of these and get the same error with both accounts.

Comment: @user147372 are you using the apikey or the Client secret?

Comment: I am 'trying' to use the 'Service Account' information since I will need to call googles api on behalf of my application. So I am not using 'Client ID for installed applications' or 'Simple API Access'